# getting the index of starting and ending 1 of a binary list having a sequence of 0s or 1s

Tags: python

I have a python list with binary information having either a sequence of 1s or a sequence of 0s for example:

```
event = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

How can I store the index values of the starting 1 and ending 1?

For example:

if `event = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]` then `result = [2,5,8,11]`

**EDIT2** i realised that result should ideally be result_start=[2,8] result_end=[5,11], like lazyr solution, this way we understand where just a single 1 located. eg. event=[0,0,1,1,0,1], would yield a wrong list for the last 1. Thanks for trying all!

**EDIT1:** I need the index of the first and the last 1 but first to the last 1.

I tried to code it like the following:

```
k=False
j=0
result=[]
for i in event:
   if i==1:
       k=True
       result.append(k)
   else:
       k=False
```

Comment: Does `event` look like the following: `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`?

Comment: @jamylak yes, its an integer list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
event = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
from itertools import izip_longest

def pair_iterator(event):
    event = [0] + event
    return enumerate(izip_longest(event, event[1:], fillvalue=0), -1)

def one_ranges(event):
    start = [i + 1 for i, pair in pair_iterator(event) if pair == (0, 1)]
    end = [i for i, pair in pair_iterator(event) if pair == (1, 0)]
    return zip(start, end)

print one_ranges(event)
```

**EDIT:**

Also find range that starts at index 0.

Created `one_ranges` function which returns a list of `(start, end)` tuples.

Answer (score 1):

As I see what you really wanted you can do something like this:

```
result = []
is_one = False
for i in range(len(event)):
    if not is_one and event[i] == 1: #Starting chain of ones
        is_one = True
        result.append(i)
    elif is_one and event[i] == 0: #Finished a chain of ones
        is_one = False
        result.append(i-1)
if is_one: #The list finished with a chain of ones
    result.append(len(event)-1)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but the question was not the best, i made an edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> event = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> event = [0] + event + [0]
>>> [i-1 for i in xrange(1,len(event)-1) if event[i]==1 and (event[i+1]==0 or event[i-1]==0)]
[2, 5, 8, 11]
```

We prepend and append the list to ensure we find the corner case of `ones` at start and/or end of list.

Comment: i did but i also just realised that @lazyr is the best solution, since, in a single list we lose the sequence of single 1s. its my fault tho.